primes with the form $q!−p$ for prime p and n consecutive integers $q \in\{k,k+1,k+2,..k+n-1\}$
I have observed that for  some integers k,p, there exists at least n positive primes with the form  $q!−p$ for n  consecutive integers $q \in\{k,k+1,k+2,..k+n-1\}$.
For example,the least integer $\{k,p\}$ for $n=1 \ to \ 7$ are as the following:
$n=1,\{3\}!-3$ are primes.
$n=2,\{4,5\}!-7$ are primes.
$n=3,\{4,5,6\}!-11$ are primes.
$n=4,\{9,10,11,12\}!-17$ are primes.
$n=5,\{22,23,24,25,26\}!-191$ are primes.
$n=6,\{12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17\}!-50377$  are primes.
$n=7,\{11,12,13,14,15,16,17\}!-92761$  are primes.
Are there any acceleration techniques to find the solution for $n=\{8,9,10...\}$ ?Or we have to brute force?
Please look at
Finding least positive integer  k>1  such that there exactly exists 100 primes with the form  m!−k

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
